# How to create right-facing arrow using loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I've been trying to create a right-facing arrow using loops. The output is supposed to look like this

```
    Output
             1
             11
        00000111
        000001111
        00000111
             11
             1
```

Heres my code

```
int height = 3;
int width = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    String row = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        row += "0";
    }
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

I dunno how to create the triangle head and i need some help putting the triangle of 1s.

Comment: Firstly you got to figure out the logic.

Comment: It might help to think of every line as a 6 or more character string. The first 5 are either spaces or zeroes depending on line number. The tack on rowNumber + 1 or 7-rowNumber 1's as needed.

Comment: i tried to use nested loops for the the first half of the triangle but it ended up either on top of the square instead of in front of it.

Comment: So print("     ") first (5 spaces between quotes) (or loop and print 1 space 5 times if you want to be more general).

Comment: I found it helpful to have a variable set either to a space or a 0 depending on the line number, and then adding width of those at the front of the string.

Comment: @güriösä, best I could do was 14 lines instead of 11. Not posting as answer because it's gross. public class MyClass {
    public static void printNofC(int n, char c) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            printNofC(5, (i >= 2 && i <= 4) ? '0' : ' ');
            printNofC((i < 4) ? i + 1 : 7 - i, '1');
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

Since the pattern is mirrored vertically, you can either do 2 loops, or a single loop that iterates around 0.

Let's follow the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and do only one loop.

```
                       i
                1     -3 = -height
                11    -2
        ┌─ 00000111   -1 = -height / 2 (truncated)
height ─┤  000001111   0
        └─ 00000111    1 = height / 2 (truncated)
                11     2
                1      3 = height
           └─┬─┘
           width
```

As for the arrowhead, the number of 1's can be calculated as `height - abs(i) + 1`.

So, you can do it all in two statements, if you use the [`repeat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) method added in Java 11.

```
for (int i = -height; i <= height; i++) {
    System.out.println((Math.abs(i) > height / 2 ? " " : "0").repeat(width) +
                       "1".repeat(height - Math.abs(i) + 1));
}
```

*Output (height = 3, width = 5)*

```
     1
     11
00000111
000001111
00000111
     11
     1
```

*Output (height = 15, width = 10)*

```
          1
          11
          111
          1111
          11111
          111111
          1111111
          11111111
0000000000111111111
00000000001111111111
000000000011111111111
0000000000111111111111
00000000001111111111111
000000000011111111111111
0000000000111111111111111
00000000001111111111111111
0000000000111111111111111
000000000011111111111111
00000000001111111111111
0000000000111111111111
000000000011111111111
00000000001111111111
0000000000111111111
          11111111
          1111111
          111111
          11111
          1111
          111
          11
          1
```

Comment: very nice answer

Answer (score 0):

For generalization drawing arrow with loop, beside width and height of straight part of arrow, you need to define width and height of triangle part

Here is the code to draw

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int heightRectangle = 3;
        int widthRectangle = 5;

        int heightTriangle = 7;
        int widthTriangle = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < heightTriangle; i++) {
            String row = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < widthRectangle + widthTriangle; j++) {
                if (j >= widthRectangle) {
                    if (i <= heightTriangle / 2) {
                        if (i >= j - widthRectangle) {
                            row = row + "1";
                        } else {
                            row = row + " ";
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (heightTriangle - i > j - widthRectangle) {
                            row = row + "1";
                        } else {
                            row = row + " ";
                        }
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                if (i < (heightTriangle - heightRectangle) / 2) {
                    row = row + " ";
                    continue;
                }
                if (i >= heightRectangle + (heightTriangle - heightRectangle) / 2) {
                    row = row + " ";
                    continue;
                }

                row = row + "0";

            }
            System.out.println(row);
        }

    }
}
```

Input:

```
 int heightRectangle = 3;
 int widthRectangle = 5;        
 int heightTriangle = 7;
 int widthTriangle = 4;
```

Output:

```
     1   
     11  
00000111 
000001111
00000111 
     11  
     1
```

Input:

```
 int heightRectangle = 6;
 int widthRectangle = 30;       
 int heightTriangle = 12;
 int widthTriangle = 6;
```

Output:

```
                              1     
                              11    
                              111   
0000000000000000000000000000001111  
00000000000000000000000000000011111 
000000000000000000000000000000111111
000000000000000000000000000000111111
00000000000000000000000000000011111 
0000000000000000000000000000001111  
                              111   
                              11    
                              1
```